# in SWRevealViewController I deleted the file But I can't add it

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I accidentally   deleted the file that create in my project 
I had imported two files in my project with this name(SWRevealViewController.h and SWRevealViewController.m) and after that the Xcode has made a file But I deleted that I can't recover that File even when I delete all of the file and add them again but that file won't be in my project

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you drag the files in, you select the option "Copy items if needed" and also select "Create groups" and at the very bottom of the same popup window, you should make sure that the target is your app and it is selected.

[image]